# html content inside span using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-content

I have a span and 5 different html structures which basically involve lists and divs.

I have 5 buttons. Clicking on each button should change the content of the span to one of these structures.

I know that it can be done as easily as using

```
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<div> A </div>";
```

But if I have an html structure of 20-30 lines, is this the best approach? Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have a bunch of such buttons, you should utilize a function that you can call with passed data in order to not have to rewrite thing voer and over again  something like

```
function insertHTML(id, content) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
}
```

Then you can just put an onclick function on you button item like this:

```
<div class="button" onclick="insertHTML('idoftarget', '<div>html</div>')"></div>
```

Comment: wouldnt it be entirely similar to what I did? Instead of putting html structure in the javascript part, this puts it in the html part.

Comment: Yes. I thought your goal was not to have a bunch the same lines (with different target elements and content) repeated over and over.

Comment: actually my main aim was to have the html content neatly arranged in the javascript side so that the html can be viewed and understood easily. but javascript has issues with multiline text right? can i put the content in the "<div> A </div>" portion across several lines?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your example is invalid.  A div tag should not go inside either an `a` tag or a `span` tag.

I would take each of the 5 HTML samples that you want to inject and make them strings in your JS and then just use innerHTML to place them into the respective container when the user clicks on one of the buttons.

Comment: you can't put a div inside a div?

Comment: He's also not putting a div inside an a tag.

Comment: @ianpgall typo, i have corrected my post by changing the second mention of `div` to `span`

Comment: so what you are saying is convert the entire html structure to a string and then put it in inner html?